# How to tell Gradle to use --console=plain all the time?

Tags: gradle, build

I am using gradle from a slightly unorthodox terminal, so Gradle's traditional "pretty" output does not work.

Is there a way I can specify in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties that `--console=plain` should be used for every gradle command?

Answer (score 11):

Since Gradle 4.3 you can add a line to a file called `gradle.properties` in your project's root directory:

```
org.gradle.console=plain
```

If you really need to make this system-wide (not just project-wide), you could make an alias for your gradle command, i.e on Linux:

```
alias gradle='gradle --console=plain'
```

Comment: This property also works in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` as asked by the OP (tested with of 5.3.1).

Answer (score 1):

you can try to add this to your `~/.gradle/init.gradle` file

```
gradle.startParameter.colorOutput = false
```

this seems to do the trick on my osx terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Use `org.gradle.console=plain`

(Padding because this post-body has to be at least 30 characters long despite the complete and accurate answer taking only 28.)